# Propper correction for multiple Fisher's exact tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, fishers-exact-test, bonferroni

I am trying to identify a list of features that are significantly over represented in one population when compared to the other. Experiment is designed such that I have two groups of individuals A and B. Each group has 20 individuals. Over 2 million features have been analyzed in these two groups and for each feature its presence/absence has been counted. As a result I have a table that looks like this:

```
  A     |      B
yes/no  |   yes/no
  8/12  |     19/1
  2/18  |     3/17
...
```

Problem is, if I apply Fisher exact test on each row and correct the obtained p-values utilizing Bonferroni correction, because of small within row counts my p-values are not low enough for Bonferroni correction to adequately address multiple testing correction. All corrected p-values after the lowest one soon become 1. How to properly correct for multiple testing given the above describe scenario?

Comment: See https://www.jstor.org/stable/2684683.